# How to list Kubernetes namespace in a single line, and delete them

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I would like to output all namespaces in a single line to a variable so I can delete the namespaces later.

Example:

```bash
TOBEDELETED=$(kubectl get namespace -o=name | grep "SOME_NAME")

eval $(kubectl delete namespace ${TOBEDELETED})
```

Comment: If you're only capturing the names and then deleting them, with no additional processing, xargs(1) might be a good fit; `kubectl get namespace -o name | grep something | xargs kubectl delete`.  If you're doing more involved processing than this than using a Kubernetes SDK in a full-featured language might be a better match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to pipe the output of your `grep` to `tr "\n" " "` to replace all newlines with spaces. Also, your `eval` is unnecessary.

```
TOBEDELETED=$(kubectl get namespace -o=name | grep "SOME_NAME" | tr "\n" " ")
kubectl delete namespace ${TOBEDELETED}
```